# Sql Stored Procedure Speed Problems

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a stored procedure, it is for getting datas on 10 table between two dates. It is return much than 1000 rows. When I call this procedure on website, sometimes it is return "website not respons" error. How should I optimize this problem.

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM banka_cariodeme WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM banka_caritahsilat WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM kasa_cariodeme WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM kasa_caritahsilat WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM cek_cariodeme WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM cek_caritahsilat WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM pos_cariodeme WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM pos_caritahsilat WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM senet_cariodeme WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
SELECT * FROM senet_caritahsilat WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
END
```

Comment: Create an index on the vade_tarihi columns and use some sort of caching in the webapplication and database.

Comment: Also, you could use the BETWEEN operator instead of the two comparisons in your where clauses.

Comment: @SloanThrasher - The parser turns `BETWEEN` into two comparisons!  (So, there is no benefit in doing it manually.)

Comment: Are any `VIEWs` involved?  Please provide `EXPLAIN` for at least one of the `SELECTs`, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there seem to be a few main possibilities in my mind:

**Possibility #1: Missing Indexes**

Imagine your table doesn't have any indexes on that date field.  So if you want to find records that match your query... the SQL engine has to look through the full table to find what it's looking for!  The idea behind an index is so that it can quickly Binary-Find the records that match

**Possibility #2: Indexes Not Used**

This one's a bit tougher to diagnose.  You'll have to use whatever query analysis tools MySql gives you (I'm not as familiar with that one) to figure it out.  But, basically, if you've got a query where the engine things the index will return too many rows to be worth it, it'll just use the main table anyways.  For instance, imagine doing a LastName != "Thomas".  Why would it use an index to figure out 99% of the rows are going be returned, and then try to match it up against the main table?  No - it'd just use the main table to begin with.

**Possibility #3: Too Much Data**

It could be that the problem is that its simply returning a lot of data.  You've got SELECT * in there - it's going to return *every single column* in the table.  Not only can this be bad design (what if a column gets added/inserted?) but it means that it's having to pass back data that might not even be getting used.

**EDIT: Possibility #4: Need A Combined Index**

I misread part of the statement the first time around, and assumed the p_dt_bas and p_dt_bts values were variables from the front end and not additional columns in the table.  In that case, there's another possibility: that it can't use any existing indexes because they don't include all the information.  After all, if you've got a query of ColA=ColB and separate indexes on each columns... it can't use the indexes.  After all, an index is just a sort of mini-table of: {indexed column(s), pointer to main table}.  So using an index of {ColA, pointer} doesn't help out finding values where ColA=ColB.  You'd need to have ColB in the *same* index.  Likewise, for a query of A < B < C, you'd need an index with all three columns.  IMPORTANT NOTE: queries like this will still not achieve Binary-Find performance.  But it'll be able to scan through just the index - not a full table scan.  Depending on how many columns your tables have, this is still a pretty important speed-up.

Comment: These are the most likely candidates.  We'd expect all of these to yield consistent behavior.  For other candidates e.g. waiting for locks or resource contention we'd expect the performance to be more sporadic. +10

Comment: I was not using index system. thanks for advices. I have a little question. I have a "id" column, it is primary key to the auto_increment. When a column be primary key is automatically indexed by this column.Should I remove primary properties on "id" column? Because I need to index on "vade_tarihi" column.

Comment: No - you can leave the index (my guess is that it's a Clustered Index) on that column.  That's standard database layout.  What you want are additional, non-clustered indexes as needed to improve performance.  My advice: do some googling and read up about how indexes work and how you they should be set up for databases.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index to the vade_tarihi columns as Peter said above would help. Adding indexes to the p_dt_bas and p_dt_bts columns would also be beneficial.

Is it necessary to pull all of the columns in those tables? Selecting just the columns that are needed (if any are not) may help the speed as well since this would reduce the overall size of the query return.

If the query is still slow after, partitioning the tables by the vade_tarihi column may also be something to consider. This would allow the query optimizer to only look as subsets of data that are relevant to the query.

If those options do not work, consider allowing the db to use more ram for caching if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an index on p_dt_bas and p_dt_bts. You can also use the BETWEEN operator in your where clause instead of doing two comparisons.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM banka_cariodeme 
        WHERE vade_tarihi between p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM banka_caritahsilat 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM kasa_cariodeme 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM kasa_caritahsilat 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM cek_cariodeme 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM cek_caritahsilat 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM pos_cariodeme 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM pos_caritahsilat 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM senet_cariodeme 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
    SELECT * FROM senet_caritahsilat 
        WHERE vade_tarihi BETWEEN p_dt_bas AND p_dt_bts 
        ORDER BY  vade_tarihi DESC;
END
```

Comment: We're just guessing, but we suspect that `p_dt_bas` and `p_dt_bts` are procedure arguments, and that `vade_tarihi` is a table column.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM banka_cariodeme WHERE (vade_tarihi >= p_dt_bas) AND (vade_tarihi <= p_dt_bts) ORDER BY vade_tarihi DESC;
```

Would be a good start and would give some information about database and indexes...